# Unable to Update or Add WCF Service Reference when HttpsGetEnabled is set to false

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, webapi

I have created a WCF service. Initially I was able to add or update service reference with my local URL **https://localhost:44390/MyService.svc.** but as soon as I changed the value of HttpsGetEnabled to false in the serviceMetaData

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
```

i am not able to add this service reference anymore neither I am able to update the service reference. I get the error shown in Bold below. how can I update or add service with both these values (httpGetEnabled,httpsGetEnabled) set to false

There was an error downloading

```
**'https://localhost:44390/MyService.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:44390/MyService.svc'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service https://localhost:44390/MyService.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.**
```

On client side I am trying to coinfugure the service in  web.config as follow

```
  <client>
      <endpoint address="https://localhost:44390/MyService.svc" binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IMyService" contract="MyWCFService.ITWCIntegrationECHO" name="BasicHttpsBinding_IMyService"/>
    </client>
```

while in my serivce I have addd the following behaviour

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9qfU.png
```

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need to specify `httpsGetEnabled` if you don't expose your service on TLS. You can delete the parameter `httpsGetEnabled` and try it out.

Comment: @Jiayao thanks, but is there any way I can add and update the service with HttpsGetEnabled set to false

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate proxies we need metadata information. The default values of `httpGetEnabled` and `httpsGetEnabled` in serviceMetadata are false. A value of false means that you did not provide metadata in WSDL format.

We can also provide data in MEX format to generate proxies like this:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexBasicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Comment: in my case it did not work, one work around that have solved my problem is in my service I have defined an other behavior and given a name to it and on client side I have used this named behavior. It look likes with HtppsGetEnabled set to false we have to used named behavior.

Comment: but still if both Http and HttpsGetEnabled are false it did not work